# JSONArray overwrites itself

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to create an Array this way:

```
json = new JSONObject();
jsArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 1; i < j; i++) {
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(i);
    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
        try {
            String ean = (String) checkBox.getText();
            json.put("ean", ean);
            jsArray.put(json);
            Log.v("jsArray", jsArray.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I get this from the code (last line is the important one):

```
04-06 19:07:02.238: V/jsArray(9894): [{"ean":"8029694000"}]
04-06 19:07:02.238: V/jsArray(9894): [{"ean":"8029694200"},{"ean":"8029694200"}]
04-06 19:07:02.238: V/jsArray(9894): [{"ean":"8029694300"},{"ean":"8029694300"},{"ean":"8029694300"}]
```

But I want this:

```
[{"ean":"8029694000"},{"ean":"8029694200"},{"ean":"8029694300"}]
```

Why the Array is overwritten with the "old" ean-variables?

Comment: it is always the same json you are adding to jsArray, repedeatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SatelliteSD stated; you're using the same `JSONObject` for each iteration. This is updating the values in THAT object each time and since the array has multiple references to the same object; it's outputting the same value multiple times.
Rewriting to something like this should resolve the issue.

```
jsArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 1; i < j; i++) {
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(i);
    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
        try {
            String ean = (String) checkBox.getText();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("ean", ean);
            jsArray.put(json);
            Log.v("jsArray", jsArray.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put your data inside the same object `json` and you also add the same reference inside you json jsArray. So when you display the content of the array it show you the content of the only reference that exist and it's the last affectation in the loop.